# A little puzzle for autoscroll (css's overflow-y enabled) effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow

There's two divs

```
<div style="height:150px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;">
    <div style="margin:5px; margin-right:25px;" onmouseover="this.style.width=(this.parentNode.offsetWidth-30)+\'px\'; this.parentNode.style.overflowY=\'auto\';" onmouseout="this.style.width=\'\'; this.parentNode.style.overflowY=\'hidden\';">';
    123<br>
    123<br>
    123<br>
    123<br>
    123<br>
    123<br>
    </div>
 </div>
```

When mouseover, there's vertical scrollbar appears (when mouseout - desappears).
The problem is, that this design doesn't work now, because scroller desappear before I can reach it to scroll. Is it possible to make this reachable that I could click on scrollbar with my mouse and move scrollbar's slider up/down?

**Important, that this task should be solved without any ids. 
'this.parentNode' and 'this' only.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on the mouseover event you reduce the width of the inner div by the parents offsetWidth - 30. This means that the mouseout event will always fire before you reach the scrollbar. You mention that the task should be solved without the use of IDs, but this can easily be solved with CSS using classes and the :hover pseudo class.

First remove the inline styles, and attach a CSS class

```
<div class="scrollable-on-hover">
    <div> ...
```

CSS:

```
.scrollable-on-hover {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.scrollable-on-hover:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

CSS fix: http://jsfiddle.net/NaKKk/1/

If you are forced to fix this using just inline javascript, you should be able to do it using this;

```
<div style="height: 150px; overflow: hidden;" onmouseover="this.style.overflowY = 'auto';" onmouseout="this.style.overflowY = 'hidden';">
    <div> ...
```

JS Fix: http://jsfiddle.net/NaKKk/2/

In the javascript example you'll notice that I attach the mouseover and mouseout events on the parent element instead of the child element. I can do this because these events will bubble up from the child element and through it's ancestor tree. Here is a simple reference to event bubbling: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventbubbling.htm

Comment: The problem is that scrolls should appear when inner DIV is onmouseovered.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine if 'firstChild' is used =)

```
<div style="height:150px; overflow:hidden; overflow-y:hidden;" onmouseover="this.firstChild.style.width=(this.offsetWidth-30)+'px'; this.style.overflowY='auto';" onmouseout="this.firstChild.style.width=''; this.style.overflowY='hidden';">
<div style="margin:5px; margin-right:25px;">';
123<br>
123<br>
123<br>
123<br>
123<br>
123<br>
</div>
```